# Embedded YouTube video on mobile web is overflowing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, youtube

A recent change on the mobile web leads to embedded YouTube videos on supported sites to be overly huge.

A while back, you couldn't scroll to see the full embedded frame, leading to text being cut off as the frame defined the box for the text. Then that was fixed, allowing a horizontal scroll bar.

But now that is gone.

Can you force the embedded YouTube frame to be the size of the default width for the design (frame size as percentage instead of fixed pixel size), or go back to the scroll bar method (overflow hidden/scrolled)?

[Sample question](//movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53212/why-and-instead-of-starring):

> [image]

Notice the video embed is roughly twice the size as the designed elements like the title bar. Since its forced to that size, two different behaviors. On Android 4.4 default browser (and likely ios devices), the browser will zoom out the full size of the page, meaning the video. On Chrome, it will make the whole page scrollable. Previously, only the specific answer or question that had the embed was scrollable, while the rest of the question was not.

Comment: Can you please give a link to post with such a "Flash"? (so we can see it for ourselves) and also screenshot is always a good idea. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard uploading images on mobile Web is really annoying and takes time. Hence the "screenshot incoming". But both link and screenshot provided. I don't have a screenshot of the old look though.

Comment: Thanks. Still can't reproduce on a desktop machine (in mobile theme), will try later on mobile device. Does it also happen with Chrome?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Chrome for android results in the whole page becoming scrollable, but does default to zoomed into the design elements. Which is very different to the previous behavior of only the DIV that held the embedded frame as scrollable.

Comment: OK, saw it. Anyway, for a while now it's not Flash any more, just HTML5.

Comment: Fix should be soon on production.

Comment: @Paweł sounds like it's fixed, time for [tag:status-completed], I guess. :)

Answer (score 2):

The sample question linked above now has a embedded frame that is sized to the design elements defaults. No more weird scrolling needed it zoom issues. It fits the page size.

A few other answers and questions also do the same.

Per @Pawel earlier comment that the fix was in production, this seems to be resolved.